# Programatically create product not showing in catalog product grid

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I created a product using below script :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setStoreId(1); 
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->addData(array(
    'name' => 'Custom Name',
    'attribute_set_id' => $product->getDefaultAttributeSetId(), 
    'status' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED, 
    'visibility' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE,      // because I don't want to show on frontend 
    'weight' => 1,
    'sku' => 'custom123',
    'tax_class_id' => 0,
    'description' => 'desciption',
    'short_description' => 'short desciption',
    'stock_data' => array( 
        'manage_stock' => 1,
        'qty' => 999, 
        'is_in_stock' => 1
    ),
));
$product->save();
```

Above script create a row in database table`catalog_product_entity` but this product not showing in magento catalog product grid.

What do I do for showing product only in magento backend?

Comment: Try after reindexing

Comment: I am having same problem and its not working even after Reindexing.

Comment: use this sample product creation code and try whether it's displaying or not
Refer this link - http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/

Comment: I have tried that also still it does not shown any product in GRID , although an product  has been created in database.

Comment: i think the tax class or some thing not added correctly. i will update an answer try that. it may help you

Comment: use `$product->setStoreId(0);` instead of `$product->setStoreId(1);`

Comment: I have tried with $product->setStoreId(0); still no new product is showing in grid.

Answer (score 0):

By missing of some required field, product doesn't show up in the backend.

Your products are showing in the database, so try to do the following:

Go to catalog -> manage products. Your current url will look like:

[yoursite.com]/index.php/admin/catalog_product/index/key/[your_key]/

Change this url to [yoursite.com]/index.php/admin/catalog_product/edit/id/[product_id]/key/[your_key]/

You can find the product ids in the database. When you enter this url, you can edit the product and check/edit product attributes, like tax class, status, etc and make sure alle required attributes are set.

I have refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608872/magento-products-not-showing-in-backend-after-importing-magento-1-3-products-to)

Comment: I tried it before, but not working for me.

Comment: do you have the product id?

Comment: In database table `catalog_product_entity` I found a new row, when run above script.

Comment: did you get the product id from the database?

Comment: when I set this product visibilty as `catalog, search` then it showing in frontend search page, but not showing in backend grid.

Comment: have you tried in the adminurl which i have given?

Comment: Yes I have tried it before as I said in my comment, I took entity_id from database and enter product/edit url, there is no required field remaining to set.

Comment: while using the url you can access the product right? if so means search the product in product grid you will get it. Sometimes the date and time of product creation may wrong.

Answer (score 0):

problem is in line 'visibility' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE,

replace VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE with VISIBILITY_BOTH